# strategy for reporting with persistence ignorance

Tags: architecture, reporting, persistence-ignorance

I need advice on a reporting strategy.  We currently use Crystal Reports, but that may be irrelevant here... we could use something different if technology choice was the issue.

I'm building an application that will handle fairly complicated invoicing but at the end of the day, they all `GetTotals`.  Persistence ignorance is going well, I'm testing in isolation and can store everything later.

But now say I want to report on invoice totals.  Generating those totals is part of the application, not the database.  I don't want to duplicate that logic in the database.  In the past, I'd build the invoicing logic into the database from the get-go but that forces me into a fairly brittle strategy application-wise.

How do I resolve this conflict?

Thank you for the advice,

-Ethan Nelson

Comment: Render unto Caesar the things which are Caesar's... If generating this totals belongs to the application do it in the application, probably your problem is that you don't know how to create data sources adn assign them to reports programatically, if that's the case then open a new question asking for advice on this.